# How to reuse fragments in a viewpager in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Say I have a viewpager with multiple fragments that hold bitmaps. I use `setOffScreenLimit(numberOfPagesInViewPager)` to make sure that the fragments are instantly available at any time (this is a requirement of my app). Quite, obviously the more fragments I have, the more memory I will use because of the bitmaps inside the fragments and fragments being kept in memory.

Now, suppose that those fragments all show the same content and therefore hold the same bitmaps.

Would it be possible to create only one fragment and reuse it in the viewpager for all pages (and hence reducing the memory footprint to 1 fragment)?

In code I am thinking about something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private MyFragment mFragment;

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);

    mFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // Reuse mFragment for all pages in the viewpager
    return mFragment;
}
}
```

This approach does not work however, as I am getting this type of error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment MyFragment{4259a4d0 id=0x7f0a0074 android:switcher:2131361908:0}: was android:switcher:2131361908:0 now android:switcher:2131361908:1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to create only one fragment and reuse it in the viewpager for all pages (and hence reducing the memory footprint to 1 fragment)?

Not with `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. And I doubt that it would work even with your own custom `PagerAdapter`.

If you use an app that has a `ViewPager`, you will notice that the `ViewPager` animates when swiping, so you see parts of two pages at one time. That will be difficult with only one page. This is why `ViewPager` requires at least three pages at all times, so it can handle swipes in either direction.

Beyond that, I cannot quite understand why users will want to flip through a series of identical pages in a `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your fragment complex? If it just has one imageview, you can implement a viewpager that uses simple layout view or just an image view as a base container.

The fragment adapter is frankly more useful if each of your fragments are of different structural code.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I believe fragments get destroyed and re-created by view pager.  You could double-check this in debugger.  If this is true, then the fragment could be a thin wrapper around a bitmap, and bitmap itself could be cached instead of a fragment.  There are multiple strategies on caching bitmaps as described at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html.